# Galois theory group automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field which is not perfect. Find out an extension $E$ of $K$ which is the splitting
field of an irreducible inseperable polynomial $f(X)$ ∈ $K[X]$ such that

$|Aut(E|K)|$ $<$ $[E : K]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the characteristic of $K$.

Since $K$ is not perfect, there exist an element $a$ in $K$ that is not a $p$th power of $K$. Then the polynomial $x^p-a$ is irreducible over $K$ and is purely inseparable. Let $E$ be the splitting field of this polynomial, we have $|\text{Aut}(E/K)| = 1$ and $[E:K] = p$.

Comment: why Aut(E/K) is one I don't get that?

Comment: For $\sigma$ in the automorphism group, since $E = K(a^{1/p})$, the value of $\sigma(a^{1/p})$ completely determines the $\sigma$, but $x^p -a = 0$ has $a^{1/p}$ as the only root.